# Best practice to access Activity from Views

Tags: android

I have a question that seems simple but I cannot figure out what is the best practice for that :)

What is the best practice to access from a **View**, a method on the **Activity** that launched the **View**?

For example, I have an Activity with a layout that contains a **Button** and a **Textfield**. I want when I click on the **Button**, to call a method on my **Activity** that update the **Textfield** with some value. I come with multiple solutions:

1 - Inner class for the **OnClickListener** directly on the **Activity** so I can the method of the **Activity** with **MyActivity.this.updateTextField()** on **onClick** method

2 - Outer class for the **OnClickListener**, on my **onClick** method I can do: **((MyActivity)getContext()).updateTextField()**

3 - Reference the **Activity** on my **OnClickListener** class when I instantiate it:
**myButton.setOnClickListener(new MyOnclickListener(MyActivity));**

I don´t want solution 1 because I don´t like that much inner class and I want reusable code. Solution 2 seems good but can produce error on runtime if my context is not an activity. Solution 3 seems good also but "heavy".

What is the best practice on Android to tell from the **View** to its **Actitity** that something needs to be done on the Activity?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I mostly find myself end up with inner classes, there are other options.
You can create an interface like the following and let your activity implement it:

```
public interface UpdateableTextField {
    public void updateTextField();
}
```

Now let the Activities that you want implement this interface.

Now, create a class that implements `View.OnclickListener` and set the constructor to get UpdateableTextField as a parameter:

```
public class MyListener implements View.OnclickListener {
    UpdateableTextField updatable;

    public MyListener(UpdateableTextField updatable) {
        this.updateable = updatable;
    }

    @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        // do some stuff
        updateable.updateTextField();
    }
}
```

And last, in the Activity:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implementes UpdateableTextField{
    @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // usuall stuff
        MyListener listener = new MyListener(this);
        someView.setOnClickListener(listener);
        // other stuff
    }

    @Override public void updateTextField() {
        // well, update the text field :)
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes that is the solution 3 and what I am doing, but it feels a little bit heavy to reference the activity on the onclicklistener istn´t it? For a desktop/web application this is good but for Android where you want to optimize the memory is it a good practice? What about for example a webview that needs to contact its activity, do I really want to do mywebview.setMyListener(this) on the activity as my activity is already referenced on the View with getContext()? I´m looking for the more optimized solution (the one used commonly).

Comment: The solution that is used commonly is your number one solution. This is the simplest way.

Comment: Ok so there is no other "integrated" solution, I thought that we could easily retrieve that information with the SDK. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

implement activity with onclickListener and add unimplemented method onclick
just check for the view to see which button is clicked incase you are using multiple buttons

Comment: It´s the same than using the solution 1, I want to be able to re-use the code. I have the same question for example on the onPageFinished on a WebView, how can I contact the activity of this webview? Is there any other better solution than the one I said?

Comment: okay @Override public void onClick(View v) {
        // do some stuff
        updateable.updateTextField();
    }
here view you are getting as argument just compare if v is equal to button1(name of your button) if yes then perform action 1 if vis equal to button2 do another action just compare to button name and reuse it

Comment: That´s not my question, I know I can implement the onclicklistener directly on the Activity, that´s not What I want because I want my onclicklistener to be in a separate class (for example myclicklistener.java).

Comment: Please follow Binyamins answer below that would best serve your purpose